# Why did I get this result via Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler

I am using the `html2text` to parse local `.html` files and it works fine.

However, if I run it by `Hadoop Streaming` to parse the same file stored in `HDFS`:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.8.0.jar -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0  -input /user/root/mapreduce/input2/xxx.html -output /user/root/mapreduce/output8  -mapper html2text.py
```

The second part of the result on `hdfs` contains the correct result as expected. However, the initial part contains some elements which are supposed to be removed, as shown below:

> if(document.URL.indexOf('tv.sohu.com')<=0){ delete this.rules["sohu"];
>   } var  handler = this.animationsHandler.bind(this);
>   document.body.addEventListener('webkitAnimationStart', handler,
>   false);    document.body.addEventListener('msAnimationStart', handler,

My question is: why this part did not appear when the `html2text` was run in local mode? and how to remove them?

Comment: It looks like you're processing 1 file, correct? How many mapper does the job give you?

Comment: yes, I am processing 1 file, and according the log, the job uses 2135 mapper. @BinaryNerd